# How to restructure a date-based folder structure containing a timestamp folder?

Tags: bash, shell, webserver, subdirectory, directory-structure

I have a date-based folder structure with an auto-generated timestamp-folder after the day-folder.

```
/2016/11/25/08151949/image.jpg
```

I need to remove the "08151949"-folder but keep the content.

```
/2016/11/25/image.jpg
```

Because I have approx. 3600 timestamp-folder I need to get that task automated. One bonus-question would be how I can build a 301-redirect which keeps url's alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your timestamp always has the same structure (in this case, 8 digits) ... You could try to create a `restructure.bash` script like the following:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Config variables
CONTENT_TO_KEEP="image.jpg"
START_PATH="/"

is_folder_timestamp() {
  local FOLDER_NAME="$1"
  # The following with match any 8-digit string, feel free to edit the regex though
  # Reference: 'man grep'; Search for 'ERE'
  local TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_REGEX='[:digit:]{8}'
  
}

# Go to start path
pushd $START_PATH


for year in *; do
  if [ -d $year ]; then
    pushd $year

    for month in *; do
      if [ -d $month ]; then
        pushd $month

        for day in *; do
          if [ -d $day ]; then
            pushd $day

              for element in *; do 
                if [ -d $element ] && `is_folder_timestamp "$element"`; then
                  # At first, I'd suggest you comment the two lines following
                  # the echo to dry-run the script and make sure you're not
                  # deleting everything ;)
                  echo "will keep content here: $pwd and rmdir $element"
                  mv $element/$CONTENT_TO_KEEP .
                  rmdir $element
                fi
              done

            popd #day
          fi
        done

        popd #month

      fi
    done

    popd # year
  fi
done

# Return to call location
popd
```

> Note that you could do without the `if [ -d $<VAR> ];` validations when you process the *year/month/day* if your structure only has directories.
> In my experience though, they don't hurt much and it keeps the script from crashing if some file event appeared in the folders ;)

Since your question tagged `python`, I guess you could then call the script using python :)

---

Relating to your **bonus question**, maybe you could add some details on the exact nature of the webserver you're running?

Hope that helped!

Comment: Great work thanks a lot! I am running webserver based on apache. So I guess that I will put a 301-Redirect with a Regex-Syntax into the .htaccess in order to remove the timestamp-folder-